# regular expression to match name initials - PCRE

Tags: php, regex, pcre, grapheme

I have a regular expression to get the initials of a name like below:

`/\b\p{L}\./gu`

it works fine with English and other languages until there are graphemes and combined charecters occur.
Like
**`क` in Hindi and

`ಕ` in Kannada** 
are being matched
But,
**`के` this one in Hindi,

`ಕೆ` this one in Kannada** are notmatched with this regex.
I am trying to get the initials from a name like J.P.Morgan, etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match diacritic marks after base letters using `\p{M}*`:

```
'~\b(?<!\p{M})\p{L}\p{M}*\.~u'
```

The pattern matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\p{M})` - the char before the current position must not be a diacritic char (without it, a match can occur within a single word)
- `\p{L}` - any base Unicode letter
- `\p{M}*` - 0+ diacritic marks
- `\.` - a dot.

See the [PHP demo online](https://3v4l.org/gdFNR):

```
$s = "क. ಕ. के. ಕೆ. ";
echo preg_replace('~\b(?<!\p{M})\p{L}\p{M}*+\.~u', '<pre>$0</pre>', $s); 
// => <pre>क.</pre> <pre>ಕ.</pre> <pre>के.</pre> <pre>ಕೆ.</pre>
```

Comment: i have a doubt @Wiktor. this one also matches the `last charecter of words` like this **ಹೇಳಿದ್ದೇ`ನೆ.`** even though there is no word break, it is picking up this combination. any idea?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Right, it is due to the diacritics. Add a negative lookbehind: `'~\b(?<!\p{M})\p{L}\p{M}*+\.~u'`